# Docker: how to to get access to interactive mode once server started in foreground?

Tags: docker

I am running Kurento on debian through Docker with

```
docker run -d --name kurento -p 8888:8888 kurento/kurento-media-server
```

That starts the kurento server. Problem is : I need to configure */etc/kurento/modules/kurento/WebRtcEndpoint.conf.ini* file that runs in docker and I have no idea on how to access it since it runs in background

When I run docker in interactive mode:

```
docker run -it --name kurento -p 8888:8888 kurento/kurento-media-server
```

the server runs in foreground, and I cannot do anything except a CTRL+C ( I tried ctrl+Z to put in in BG process)

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to input an initial configuration file, the best way is by using a volume when starting:

`docker run -d --name kurento -p 8888:8888 -v /etc/kurento/modules/kurento/:/path/to/your/env/kurento kurento/kurento-media-server`

and inside `/path/to/your/env/kurento` will be your `WebRtcEndpoint.conf.ini` file

If you just want to jump inside the machine and tinker around, you can 'exec bash':

`docker exec -it kurento /bin/bash`

Answer (score 0):

Once your container is started and running, you can create a bash session in that container with below command:

```
docker exec -ti <container_name> bash
```